# Woocommerce.NET + C#: get the ID of product from SKU

Tags: c#, woocommerce-rest-api

I am making a small app using C# with Woocommerce.NET wrapper.
I would like to edit a product, but I do not have the ID of a product - only SKU.

What would be the easiest way to get product ID from SKU number?

I have tried this:

```
RestAPI rest = new RestAPI(url, key, secret); 
WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);  

var products = wc.Product.GetAll().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

products.ForEach(p => if p.sku = productSKU)
    {
        var productIDfromSKU = p.id;
    }
```

EDIT: I have changed the code, to convert to int and it now works!

```
foreach (var p in products)
     {
      if (p.sku == SKU)
           {
            IDfromSKU = Convert.ToInt32(p.id);

             };
       };
```

But the problem is, that I only get a list of 10 products - not all. 
Is there a setting for that?
My question remain -  Is there a more straight forward way?

EDIT 2:

I have implemented your answers, the code works, but it is terribly slow.
2-3 minutes on ~5000 products.

What can I do to speed things up?

EDIT 3:

Sorry,  have not done enough testing - the second answer great!

```
string SKU = "***wanted SKU***";
List<Product> products  = new List<Product>();
Dictionary<string, string> pDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
pDic.Add("sku", SKU);

int productIDfromSKU = 0;
string productNamefromSKU  = "";
products  = await wc.Product.GetAll(pDic);
if (products.Count > 0)
{
    productIDfromSKU = Convert.ToInt32(products[0].id);
    productNfromSKU = products[0].name;
}
```

Consider my problem solved!

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        RestAPI rest = new RestAPI(url, key, secret); 
        WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);

        string SKU = "***wanted SKU***";
        List<Product> products  = new List<Product>();
        Dictionary<string, string> pDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        pDic.Add("sku", SKU);

        int productIDfromSKU = 0;
        string productNamefromSKU  = "";
        products  = await wc.Product.GetAll(pDic);
        if (products.Count > 0)
        {
            productIDfromSKU = Convert.ToInt32(products[0].id);
            productNfromSKU = products[0].name;
        }
```

Comment: Instead of making multiple answers why not update your original answer? It helps keep things clean for others. Also, do you know about LINQ? It makes working with enumerables a lot easier. Instead of products[0] you can use products.FirstOrDefault(), products.First(), or products.Single() depending on what your code is expecting. Single() looks like the right choice in this case, since your code wants 1 and only 1 result.

Answer (score 1):

```
        RestAPI rest = new RestAPI(url, key, secret); 
        WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);              

        List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
        Dictionary<string, string> dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dic1.Add("per_page", "100");
        int pageNumber1 = 1;
        dic1.Add("page", pageNumber1.ToString());

        bool endWhile1 = false;
        while (!endWhile1)
        {
            var productsTemp = await wc.Product.GetAll(dic1);
            if (productsTemp.Count > 0)
            {
                products.AddRange(productsTemp);
                pageNumber1++;
                dic1["page"] = pageNumber1.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                endWhile1 = true;
            }
        }

        foreach (Product p in products)
        {
           if (p.sku == SKU)
           {
               IDfromSKU = Convert.ToInt32(p.id);
               break;
           };
        }
```

Comment: An explanation on what you're doing to resolve the problem would be helpful.